# Is there a way to get some realistic photo filters in Flash with AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, filter, matrix, photo

Does anyone know or can point me in the right direction on how to reproduce the Photoshop Image/Adjustments/Photo filters... in Flash with AS3. Is the same result that you get when you put a filter over the lenses of a camera. I exclude using tint and hue from the start because it doesn't help me at all, I think could get this from code by using color matrix class or convolution filter, any ideas??

Comment: yes, you could reproduce a few using the ConvolutionFilter, but do have a look at PixelBender as well.

Comment: Hey. Im looking for a way to convert my Photoshop values to color matrix too. Did you find a solution? Ive edited the Hue/Saturation/Contrast/Levels/Channel Mixer . Would you have ColorMatrix tables for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ColorMatrixFilter is definitely your best bet.. Here's a quick example on making a DisplayObject black & white.

```
var bnw:Array = [1.2,0,0,0,0,1.2,0,0,0,0,1.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0];
var filter:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(bnw);

yourDisplayObject.filters = [filter];
```

The actual values confuse the heck out of me, I just play around. It mostly makes sense.. This will give you a little more info:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html

Comment: Also here is a good run-down on what you can achieve and how the values work: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/04/28/understanding-as3-colormatrixfilter-class/

Comment: Any place where there is a dump of existing ColorMatrixFilters or where people exchange scripts?

Comment: @summers Nothing that I know of. I guess you're looking for something like [snazzy maps](https://snazzymaps.com/) but I haven't come across anything like that.

Comment: There are no ColorMatrises on snazzy maps. Is there a way to see the ColorMatrix used in those maps?

Comment: @summers No sorry I meant you are looking for something like snazzy maps but for a collection of ColorMatrixFilters.

Comment: Ah Yes! :D  Sounds like something that should be out there right? Unfortunately cant find anything